# jquery only refresh div after 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem im not able to only refresh one div after 3 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#online-users-random").html();
    }, 5000);
});


<div id="online-users" class="online-users">
    <span>Online: </span><span><?php echo rand(1,1000); ?></span>
</div>
```

I want just refresh the div i also tried something like `.load etc... but its not option that i need`

At least i found the solution....

```
function auto_load(){
                        $.ajax({
                          url: "LINK",
                          cache: false,
                          success: function(data){
                             $("#online-users-random").html(data);
                          } 
                        });
                }

                $(document).ready(function(){

                auto_load();

                });

                setInterval(auto_load,5000);
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the PHP code again? It's not going to work this way. The PHP code runs on the server and the JS code runs on the browser.

Comment: Yes i want if the jquery refresh the div the number or something will be changed but i need it in php

Comment: If you want to retrieve data dynamically from your server, you'll need to use `ajax`.

Comment: Still cant find solution